# Is there a method to form a CI based on an MLE which is not the mean

Tags: confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, inference

I know how to find confidence intervals for parameters based on sample means. I want to know whether there exists a method for finding confidence intervals based on MLE's which are not sample means.

Any illustration would be helpful. Or, you may link me to some relevant website.

Comment: What exactly do you have in mind? If you want one-size-fit-all solution, then you can consider bootstrap as you can use it for creating CI's for literally anything.

Comment: MLE's generally have better properties than almost any other estimator. So I was thinking that if in a situation the MLE fails to be the sample mean, then whether we can find a CI. I realize that if a solution to this exists, the distribution must be a general one. It should be amenable in some way to CLT, because otherwise we can't find a CI.

Comment: There are times when the MLE is the sample mean where the interval doesn't necessarily work the way you expect. For example, if $X_i\sim \text{exponential}(\mu)$; ($f(x)=\frac{1}{\mu}\exp(-\frac{x}{\mu})\,I_{(0,\infty)}(x)$), the sample mean is ML for $\mu$, but how are you going to get an interval for it?

Comment: Using the delta method often helps.

Comment: Okay; how does it help here?  I'm curious why you think the mean is somehow different. (Note that the method suggested in my answer works fine, but your question reads like you have a general small-sample method for means.)

Comment: Exactly what I am trying to say. I can use the mean in the Delta Method to get a CI for the parameter. But suppose I have an MLE, then I can't apply Delta Method to it. And any information regarding MLE will work: small sample, large sample, whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are several. I'll illustrate one. This doesn't always work (you may not be able to find a suitable quantity, for example).

One common approach to generate confidence intervals for parameters is via [pivotal quantities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivotal_quantity).

A pivotal quantity is a function of the parameter and a statistic whose distribution doesn't depend on the parameter. You can then form an interval for the pivotal quantity (which will be the same no matter what the parameter value is), and from that back out an interval for the parameter.

So for example, consider the variance parameter for a normal distribution; $Q=(n-1)\frac{s^2}{\sigma^2}\sim\chi^2_{n-1}$.

To be specific, let's say n=15, and $s^2=28.5$.

From the $\chi^2_{14}$ distribution, a 99% interval for $Q$ is $4.075<Q<31.32\,$. So

$4.075<(n-1)\frac{s^2}{\sigma^2}<31.32$

$4.075<14\times 28.5/{\sigma^2}<31.32$

$1/31.32<\frac{\sigma^2}{14\times 28.5}<1/4.075$

$\frac{14\times 28.5}{31.32}<\sigma^2<\frac{14\times 28.5}{4.075}$

$12.74<\sigma^2<97.91$

So a 99% interval for $\sigma^2$ is $(12.74, 97.91)$